# PHP - Not all images get uploaded

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, pdo

This problem has baffled me for a while now. Basically I have a form that when submitted will upload multiple images at the same time to the server and also insert a record of each image into a Mysql database.

Currently I can select and upload up to 6 images successfully to the server and have their records inserted into the mysql database.

If I select 7 images only 6 get uploaded. This is the same if I select 8, 9 or 10 images; its always one less than the total number that I selected that get uploaded.

If I select 11 images and submit the form nothing happens, no images get uploaded and no records of the images get inserted into the database.

I checked the images and all are within the allowed filetype, size, dimensions etc. the php.ini file for the webserver I'm using has max_file_uploads set to 200.

So why does it upload all but one of my images in one instance and in another doesn't upload any of them?

The code is quite long, I'll try and only include the applicable stuff.

additem.php:

```
//check if the submit button has been clicked
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

        //validate the title and description
        $title = validate_title($_POST['title']);
        $desc = validate_desc($_POST['desc']);

        //Get other posted variables
        $cat = $_POST['cat'];
        $year = $_POST['year'];

        if($title && $desc != false){


            //check if an image has been submitted
            if((!empty($_FILES["files"])) && ($_FILES['files']['error'][0] == 0)){

                // Insert the post
                insert_post_db($title, $desc, $year);

                // Get id of last inserted post
                $post_id = get_postid();

                // loop through each individual image
                foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){ 

                    // Get the image info
                    $temp_dir = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key]; // Temporary location of file
                    $image_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key]; // Image filetype
                    $image_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key]; // Image file size
                    $image_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]; // Image file name

                    // Get image width and height
                    $image_dimensions = getimagesize($temp_dir); // returns an array of image info [0] = width, [1] = height
                    $image_width = $image_dimensions[0]; // Image width
                    $image_height = $image_dimensions[1]; // Image height

                    // Check to make sure there are no errors in ther file
                    if($_FILES['files']['error'][$key] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK){

                        // Make sure each filename name is unique when it is uploaded
                        $random_name = rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999);

                        // Set the path to where the full size image will be stored
                        $path = 'img/fullsize/'.$random_name . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];

                        // Set the path to where the thumb image will be stored
                        $thumb_path = 'img/thumb_/'.$random_name .$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];

                        // Set the Maximum dimensions the images are allowed to be
                        $max_width = 4040;
                        $max_height = 4040;

                        // Set the Maximum file size allowed (5MB)
                        $max_size = 5242880;

                        // Set the file extensions that are allowed to be uploaded and store them in an array
                        $allowed = array('image/jpeg','image/png','image/gif');

                        // Check to make sure the image that is being uploaded has a file extension that we permit
                        if(in_array($image_type,$allowed)){
                            // Check to make sure the Image dimensions do not exceed the maximum dimensions allowed
                            if(($image_width < $max_width) && ($image_height < $max_height)){ 
                                // Check to make sure the Image filesize does not exceed the maximum filesize allowed
                                if($image_size < $max_size){ 

                                    // Check the shape of the Image (square, standing rectangle, lying rectangle) and assign a value depening on which it is
                                    $case = image_shape($image_width, $image_height);

                                    // Create the new thumbnail dimensions
                                    list($thumb_width, $thumb_height, $smallestside, $x, $y) = thumb_dimensions($case, $image_width, $image_height, $smallestside, $x, $y);

                                    // Create the thumbnails
                                    create_thumbnail($image_type, $image_height, $image_height, $temp_dir, $thumb_path, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $smallestside, $x, $y);

                                    // move large image from the temporary location to the permanent one
                                    move_uploaded_file($temp_dir, $path);

                                    // Get the new randomly generated filename and remove the directory name from it
                                    $file_name = substr($path, 4);

                                    // Insert a record of the image in the Database
                                    insert_image_db($file_name, $cat, $post_id,$image_size, $image_width, $image_height);

                                    // Tell user image was successfully uploaded
                                    echo "<p>Image uploaded ok.</p>";

                                    // Forward to the review post page
                                    header('Location: reviewpost.php');
                                }else{
                                    echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$key] . ': unsupported file size.';
                                }
                            }else{
                                echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$key] . ': unsupported image dimensions.';
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$key] . ': unsupported filetype.';
                        }
                    }else{echo 'file error';}
                }



            }else{
                //display error message if user didnt select an image to upload
                echo '<p>There was an error processing your submission. Please select an image to upload.</p>';
            }
        }else{
            //display error message if the title or description are incorrect length
            echo errormessage($title, $desc);
        }
    }
```

functions:

```
// Find out what shape the image is
    function image_shape($image_width, $image_height){
        if($image_width == $image_height){$case=1;} // square image
        if($image_width < $image_height){$case=2;} // standing rectangle
        if($image_width > $image_height){$case=3;} // lying rectangle
        return $case;

    }

    // Set the dimensions of the new thumbnail 
    function thumb_dimensions($case, $image_width, $image_height){
        switch($case){
            case 1:
                $thumb_width    =   200;
                $thumb_height   =   200;
                $y = 0;
                $x = 0;
                $smallestside = $image_height;
            break;
            case 2:
                $thumb_height   =   200;
                $ratio          =   $thumb_height / $image_height;
                $thumb_width    =   round( $image_width * $ratio );
                $x = 0;
                $y = ($image_height - $image_width) /2;
                $smallestside = $image_width;
            break;
            case 3:
                $thumb_width    =   200;
                $ratio          =   $thumb_width / $image_width;
                $thumb_height   =   round($image_height * $ratio);
                $x = ($image_width - $image_height) /2;
                $y = 0;
                $smallestside = $image_height;
            break;
        }
        return array($thumb_width, $thumb_height, $smallestside, $x, $y);
    }

    // Create a thumbnail of the image
    function create_thumbnail($image_type, $image_width, $image_height, $temp_dir, $thumb_path, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $smallestside, $x, $y){
        switch($image_type){
            case 'image/jpeg';
                $thumbsize = 200;
                $img =      imagecreatefromjpeg($temp_dir);
                $thumb =    imagecreatetruecolor($thumbsize, $thumbsize);
                            imagecopyresized($thumb, $img, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbsize, $thumbsize, $smallestside, $smallestside);
                            imagejpeg($thumb, $thumb_path,100);


            break;
            case 'image/png';
                $thumbsize = 200;
                $img =      imagecreatefrompng($temp_dir);
                $thumb =    imagecreatetruecolor($thumbsize, $thumbsize);
                            imagecopyresized($thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbsize, $thumbsize, $smallestside, $smallestside);
                            imagepng($thumb, $thumb_path, 0);

            break;
            case 'image/gif';
                $thumbsize = 200;
                $img =      imagecreatefromgif($temp_dir);
                $thumb =    imagecreatetruecolor($thumbsize, $thumbsize);
                            imagecopyresized($thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbsize, $thumbsize, $smallestside, $smallestside);
                            imagegif($thumb, $thumb_path, 100);

            break;
        }

    }
    function insert_post_db($title, $desc, $year){
        //test the connection
        try{
            //connect to the database
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mjbox","root", "usbw");
        //if there is an error catch it here
        } catch( PDOException $e ) {
            //display the error
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO mjbox_posts(post_year,post_desc,post_title,post_active,post_date)VALUES(?,?,?,?,NOW())");
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$year);
        $stmt->bindParam(2,$desc);
        $stmt->bindParam(3,$title);
        $stmt->bindValue(4,"0");
        $stmt->execute();


    }
    function insert_image_db($file_name, $cat, $post_id, $image_size, $image_width, $image_height){

        //test the connection
        try{
            //connect to the database
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mjbox","root", "usbw");
        //if there is an error catch it here
        } catch( PDOException $e ) {
            //display the error
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        //insert images
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO mjbox_images(img_file_name,cat_id,post_id,img_size,img_width,img_height,img_is_thumb) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$file_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(2,$cat);
        $stmt->bindParam(3,$post_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(4,$image_size);
        $stmt->bindParam(5,$image_width);
        $stmt->bindParam(6,$image_height);
        $stmt->bindValue(7,"0");
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

Sorry that it's a lot of code, I tried to only include the stuff that might be applicable, let me know if I missed something.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a usleep timer in between of each file. I just tried it and it works for me. I put 0.3 seconds.

```
foreach($file .. $k => $v) {
    // your stuff above..
    usleep(300000); // Sleep between each file, 1000000 = 1 second
}
```